# Accessing elements of JSON object without knowing the key names

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, vb.net, for-loop

Here's my json:

```
{"d":{"key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2"}}
```

Is there any way of accessing the keys and values (in javascript) in this array without knowing what the keys are?

The reason my json is structured like this is that the webmethod that I'm calling via jquery is returning a dictionary. If it's impossible to work with the above, what do I need to change about the way I'm returning the data?

Here's an outline of my webmethod:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function Foo(ByVal Input As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim Results As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    'code that does stuff

    Results.Add(key,value)
    Return Results
End Function
```

Comment: *"accessing the keys and values (in javascript) in this array"* - what array..?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use the `for..in` construct to iterate through arbitrary properties of your object:

```
for (var key in obj.d) {
    console.log("Key: " + key);
    console.log("Value: " + obj.d[key]);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Do I still need to use a `for in` if there is only one key value pair?

Comment: @Radu You can't access the properties of an object with indices, so you will need to get the key(s) using a for...in.

Comment: What if the JSON has a list of objects and you want to get the object names? Like {"d":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},"e":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}} and you want name of d and e, but you don't know they're called d and e at runtime.

Comment: The "key" variable in the top-level iteration would give you the "object names".

Comment: You might need to use `obj.d.hasOwnProperty(key)` inside for block to get rid of the inner private properties.

Answer (score 13):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var data;
for (var key in data) {
   var value = data[key];
   alert(key + ", " + value);
}
```

Comment: Tip: Don't call JavaScript objects JSON objects. JSON is the transport format. Once parsed, there's no JSON.

Comment: Tip2: A more concise way to alert multiple values: `alert([key, value])`

Comment: @Ates Goral My implication with the var name was that it contained the JSON data, not that it was a JSON object. Poor choice, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted the other answer as it was slightly better tuned to my json data.

Comment: @Radu You're welcome, and no problem. Glad we were able to help you.

Answer (score 6):

```
{
  "d":{
     "key1":"value1",
     "key2":"value2"
    }
}
```

To access first key write:

```
   let firstKey=Object.keys(d)[0];
```

To access value of first key write:

```
let firstValue= d[firstKey];
```

Answer (score 3):

By using word "b", You are still using key name.

```
var info = {
"fname": "Bhaumik",
"lname": "Mehta",
"Age": "34",
"favcolor": {"color1":"Gray", "color2":"Black", "color3":"Blue"}
};
```

Look at the below snippet.

```
for(key in info) {
  var infoJSON = info[key];
  console.log(infoJSON);
}
```

Result would be,

```
Bhaumik
Mehta
Object {color1: "Gray", color2: "Black", color3: "Blue"}
```

Don’t want that last line to show up? Try following code:

```
for(key in info) {
  var infoJSON = info[key];
    if(typeof infoJSON !== "object"){
       console.log(infoJSON);
  }
}
```

This will eliminate `Object {color1: “Gray”, color2: “Black”, color3: “Blue”}` from showing  up in the console.

Now we need to iterate through the variable infoJSON to get array value. Look at the   following whole peace of code.

```
for(key in info) {
    var infoJSON = info[key];
    if (typeof infoJSON !== "object"){
       console.log(infoJSON);
    }
 }

for(key1 in infoJSON) {
    if (infoJSON.hasOwnProperty(key1)) {
       if(infoJSON[key1] instanceof Array) {
          for(var i=0;i<infoJSON[key1].length;i++) {
             console.log(infoJSON[key1][i]);
          }
        } else {console.log(infoJSON[key1]);}
    }
 }
```

And now we got the result as

```
Bhaumik
Mehta
Gray
Black
Blue
```

If we use key name or id then it’s very easy to get the values from the JSON object but here we are getting our values without using key name or id.

Answer (score 3):

Use for loop to achieve the same.

```js
var dlist = { country: [ 'ENGLAND' ], name: [ 'CROSBY' ] }

for(var key in dlist){
     var keyjson = dlist[key];
     console.log(keyjson)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a `response` like this :

```
{
  "d":{
     "key1":"value1",
     "key2":"value2"
  },
  "e":{
     "key1":"value1",
     "key2":"value2"
   }
}
```

The first value can be accessed thus:

```
let firstValue = object.values(response.d)[0];
```