# Accessing a JavaScript's object property without knowing that property name

Tags: javascript, object, properties

**Situation**

I have a JSON object which is returned. And Below is an example of one. The `who` in this particular example can change to whatever property name is required. So for example next time this will be `name` rather than `who`

```
 [{"who":"Arthur"},{"who":"Craig"},{"who":"Dan"},{"who":"Daniel"},{"who":"Frank"},{"who":"Ian"},{"who":"jamie"},{"who":"Jason"},{"who":"jaz"},{"who":"Liam"},{"who":"Paul"},{"who":"Shaun"},{"who":"Wayne"}]
```

**Problem**

In my JS I need to be able to refer to the property and access its data without using its name as the name will always be something different.

**What I have tried**

```
data.forEach(function(m){
    console.info(m); // Object { who="Craig"}
    console.info(m.who); // Craig, as expected
    console.info(m[0]); // now not sure who to get it if who changes to name
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for `m['who']`?

Comment: indeed, this would be how I can return who. But I need to be able to return an string. So m['*'] effectively. I do not know the name of the property.

Comment: Gotcha, answer added.

Comment: does anyone know if this is possible using a jpath query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing elements of JSON object without knowing the key names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113847/accessing-elements-of-json-object-without-knowing-the-key-names)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`Object.keys(m)[0]` should return the first enumerable property name in the object `m`.

So if `m = {"who": "Arthur"};` then `m[Object.keys(m)[0]]` will be `"Arthur"`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

---

Alternatively: `Object.values(m)[0]`. See [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `for in` loop:

```
data.forEach( function ( m ) {
    
  for ( const key in m ) {

    console.log( key ); // "who"
    console.log( m[key] ); // "Arthur"

  }

});
```

The above would also work for multiple `key: value` pairs in your object i.e:

```
[ {"who": "Arthur", "who": "Fred"}, {"who": "Craig"}, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always expect these objects to have only one property, you could do something like this:

```
var name, person;
for (person in data) {
    for (name in data[person]) {
        console.log(data[person][name]);
    }
}
```

This would enumerate through each property of each person in the data. Because there is only one property per person (I assume), it will just enumerate that one property and stop, allowing you to use that property regardless of its name.