# Check if MySQL row exists - Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

[Previous post I will refer to later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table)

I am making a Discord bot which uses MySQL, but that shouldn't matter, I am trying to do a blacklist database so users in it can't use my bot

This is what I got so far:

```
con.query("SELECT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM `blacklist` WHERE `id` = '"+message.author.id+"')", function(error, result, field) {
    if(error) throw error;
});
```

And this kinda works, this is my output

```
[ RowDataPacket {
'EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM `blacklist` WHERE `id` = \'227090776172134400\')': 1 } ]
```

And the last digit works like a boolean, 1 if the row exists, 0 if it does not
But my problem is, that I can't seem to figure out how to check if it's a zero or not because it's an object

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16576485/6608395) on how to access the property of an object

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you make the query string a variable that you can later query on. For example:

```
let conStr = "SELECT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM `blacklist` WHERE `id` = '"+message.author.id+"')";
con.query(conStr, function(error, result, field) {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(result[conStr]); //--> 1
});
```