# Access elements inside json object without knowing names

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, javascript-objects

I have the following json object in node.js.

```
x={
    '40': {
        length: '2',
        data: ['11', '22']
    },
    '41': {
        length: '1',
        data: ['fe']
    },
    '42': {
        length: '2',
        data: ['ef', 'ab']
    },  
}
```

Suppose I do not know in advance what will be the property name inside `x`. However, I would like to retrieve every property and its associated value. How can this be done?

I am using node.js

Comment: `for (var key in x) { var value = x[key] }`

Comment: maybe use index of object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing elements of JSON object without knowing the key names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113847/accessing-elements-of-json-object-without-knowing-the-key-names)

Comment: None of the current answers return "every property and its associated value", just the top level fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion to find the key/values of all objects nested or otherwise:

```
function finder(obj) {

  // for each property in the object passed into
  // the function...
  for (var p in obj) {

    // if its value is another object (see appended note)...
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[p]).slice(8, -1) === 'Object') {

      // ...log the key to the console and then call finder()
      // again with this current object (this is the recursive part)
      console.log('key: ' + p + ', value: Object');
      finder(obj[p]);

    // otherwise log the key/value
    } else {
      console.log('key: ' + p + ', value: ', obj[p]);
    }
  }
}

finder(x);
```

OUTPUT

```
key: 40, value: Object
key: length, value:  2
key: data, value:  Array [ "11", "22" ]
key: 41, value: Object
key: length, value:  1
key: data, value:  Array [ "fe" ]
key: 42, value: Object
key: length, value:  2
key: data, value:  Array [ "ef", "ab" ]
```

NOTE

This rather long-winded line of code to check if a value is an object

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[p]).slice(8, -1) === 'Object'
```

is necessary because `typeof obj[p] === 'object'` will return `true` for arrays and `null` too. It's a bit of a gotcha.

```
Object.prototype.toString.call({})
```

returns a string like `"[object Object]"`, and the `slice` grabs the relevant section of the string.

Comment: Thanks. Marked as right answer. Your answer more completely answers my question. But I need some time to understand the code.

Comment: I'll annotate it Give me a sec.

Comment: Updated the answer @LitAiy.

Answer (score 4):

First, that's not JSON. That's a JavaScript object initializer. JSON is a *textual* notation. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. (If that *were* a string, it would be invalid JSON; JSON requires that keys and strings be in double quotes, not single quotes.)

You can find out what the keys in the `x` object are using `for-in` or `Object.keys`:

#### `for-in`:

```
var key;
for (key in x) {
    // key is the key
    // x[key] is the value
}
```

With the latest NodeJS, you can use JavaScript's new `let` to keep `key` scoped just to the loop:

```
for (let key in x) {
    // key is the key
    // x[key] is the value
}
```

#### `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys(x).forEach(function(key) {
    // key is the key
    // x[key] is the value
});
```

In recent versions of NodeJS you can use JavaScript's new *arrow function* as the callbck to make things more concise:

```
Object.keys(x).forEach(key => {
    // key is the key
    // x[key] is the value
});
```

---

If you need to descend into the objects contained with `x`, you simply recurse.

Note that `for-in` will visit the object's *enumerable properties*, including any enumerable properties on its prototype(s). `Object.keys` will give you an array of the object's *own enumerable properties* (only).

Example of `forEach`:

```js
var x = {
    '40': {
        length: '2',
        data: ['11', '22']
    },
    '41': {
        length: '1',
        data: ['fe']
    },
    '42': {
        length: '2',
        data: ['ef', 'ab']
    },  
};
Object.keys(x).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key + ": length = " + x[key].length);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the `for-in` method. Looks more readable. But is Object.keys more powerful? It looks like it can do more.

Comment: @LitAiy: One of the nice things about using `Object.keys` is that you get a nice contained scope for your `key` and perhaps `value` variable (the scope of the callback). But you can use JavaScript's new `let` to do that with `for-in`, too.

Comment: thanks for the answer and explanation. Apologies for switching answer to Andy but his answer was more complete for my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()`:

```
Object.keys(x).forEach(v => {
    console.log(v);  // logs the key
    console.log(x[v])  // logs the key's value
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Optimizing the Andy's code

```js
var x = {
        '40': {
            length: '2',
            data: ['11', '22']
        },
        '41': {
            length: '1',
            data: ['fe']
        },
        '42': {
            length: '2',
            data: ['ef', 'ab']
        },  
    };



function finder(obj) {
   
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1) === 'Object') {

    for (var p in obj) {
        console.log('key: ' + p + ', type: object');
        finder(obj[p]);
     } 
  } else {
      console.log('key: ' + obj + ', value: ', obj);
  }
  
}

finder(x);
```

Comment: The property names `length` and `data` are not known.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks I'll add some